# Allowances for Cremation

Tags: halacha, funeral-burial-levaya, fire-burning

Are there any Jewish sources that permit cremation? Jews generally frown upon cremation since the body was created by G-d and should be treated with respect (out of respect for G-d). However, some biblical figures such as King Saul were cremated since his body was mutilated by the Philistines and had decomposed.

Are their other circumstances in which cremation is necessary, say if a person died in a fire. And if so, what are the spiritual components.

Sources, please.

Comment: See the Radak on those passages concerning King Saul

Comment: If there's a danger to life.  Apparently it's recommended for people who die of Ebola R"l

Comment: The Radak :וישרפו אותם שם. ת"י וקלו עליהון כמא דקלן על מלכיא תמן אפשר שהיה דעתו כמו שכתבו רבותינו ז"ל שורפין על המלכים ומה הם שורפין עליהם מטתן וכלי תשמישן או דעתו על שריפת בשמים כמו ויחנטו הרופאים ויתכן לפרש כי הבשר שרפו שהעלה רמה ולא רצו לקברם עם התולעים כי לא היה דרך כבוד ושרפו הבשר וקברו העצמות: acc to the Radak the burning may refer to his possessions, and if you want to say it refers to his body it was only the flesh that was burned due to worms ,but the bones remained intact for burial.

Comment: https://www.timesofisrael.com/state-mandated-cremation-a-posthumous-mitzvah-says-leading-orthodox-rabbi/ @Heshy

Comment: @Heshy Thank you.